# Making sense of .so file: trying to restore poorly versioned source files

Tags: gdb, shared-libraries

If this question is too generic, please tell me so i can delete it.

I have a software used in operation that is compiled with linking to a .so file. The file is generated in compilation of a set of versioned .c and .cpp sources. Previous developer generated the .so file compiling a local version of source files that was modified in unknown ways and modified sources are god-knows where, if anywhere in the system at all. Fortunately it was compiled with debugging symbols, so reading it with gdb is easier.

Software is being used in operation and i need to modify it. Recompiling any known version of it will obviously generate results that differ from current compiled version in unknown ways. I want to dig as deep as possible in current .so file to know what it is doing, so that i can recompile sources generating as similar a result as i can. What i did until now:

- `readelf --debug-dump=info path/to/file | grep "DW_AT_producer"` to see compilation flags and reproduce them in new compilations.
- `(gdb) info functions` to see what functions are defined and compare it with previous versions of code.
- Going function by function on the functions listed by previous command and: `list <function>`

Does anyone have any more tips on how to get as much info from .so file as i can? Since im not expert with gdb yet: am i missing something important?

Edit: by using strip in both files (compiled from original source and compiled from mysterious lost source file) i managed to see that most of differences between them were just debug symbols (which is weird because it seems both were compiled with -g option).

There is only one line of difference between them now.

Comment: I just found out that "list" just reads the source file from the binary, so list doesn't help me in my case since the file that is in path of source file is clearly not the actual source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just found out that "list" just reads the source file from the binary, so list doesn't help me

You are confused: the source is never stored in the binary. GDB `list` command is showing the source *as it exists* in some file on disk.

The `info sources` command will show *where* on disk GDB is reading the sources from.

If you are lucky, that's the sources that were used to build the `.so` binary, and your task is trivial -- compare them to VCS sources to find modifications.

If you are unlucky, the sources GDB reads have been overwritten, and your task is much harder -- effectively you'll need to reverse-engineer the `.so` binary.

The way I would approach the harder task: build the library from VCS sources, and then for each function compare `disas fn` between the two versions of `.so`, and study differences (if any).

P.S. I hope you are also using the exact same version of the compiler that was used to compile the in-production `.so`, otherwise your task becomes much harder still.

Comment: Date of last modification in .so file is older than date of last modification in source and compiler files, so my task unfortunately wont be trivial :( Thanks for the answer: i was trying to use list but it clearly wont be my solution. `disas foo` seems more accurate.
Yes i am using exactly the same compiler, compiler version, flags, etc.
I managed to make both .so files much more similar using the strip command before actually looking at them.
Im assuming using strip is a good way of comparison because i assume it never changes functionality but just removes debug symbols. Is this right?

Comment: @MarcoMontevechiFilho Yes, that is correct.

Comment: CoAfter using `strip` i scripted disassemble of all functions in both versions of compiled code. No difference was found in disassemble. After `strip`, difference in both binaries is very very small: one single non-printable character. sha256sum of files is still different.
Any hint on what could be the difference or how to find out what it means?

Comment: Finally: after using `readelf -a my_file.so > log.txt` and comparing: the only difference is the build ID. (facepalm).
Im not familiar with what is build ID and why it is identical in new compilations, but i will find out.

Comment: @MarcoMontevechiFilho The build-id is a unique checksum added by the linker and computed over all "important" bits of the `ELF` file. Chances are you have `__DATE__` used somewhere in the library, and so can't get bit-identical result. If all the disassembly matches, and all of `readelf --all` matches except for build-id, you are in a pretty good place. The global data might still be different though. You can extract such data with `readelf -x .data` and `readelf -x .rodata`, and compare these separately.

Comment: `readelf -x .data` and `readelf -x .rodata` are identical for both files. You spared me from a lifetime of suffering and gnashing of teeth, good sir.