# Understanding ELF file build ID

Tags: build, elf

Im [comparing two binary files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75436070/making-sense-of-so-file-trying-to-restore-poorly-versioned-source-files/75438715?noredirect=1#comment133112160_75438715) generated by versions of same code that could or could not be equal. Meld showed a small difference between the binaries, but completely disassembling both binaries revealed that every function defined was identical.

Suspecting file metadata i did:

```
readelf -a my_file1.so > log1.txt
readelf -a my_file2.so > log2.txt
diff log1.txt log2.txt
```

Result is:

```
772c772
<     Build ID: 067b24a4b8afa6c823ffb5462d344c5021496b66
---
>     Build ID: 7925f5c881822348c17221fd1420e7df9fdb5633
```

I found no good explanation of what is elf-file build id, so my main question is:

My recompilations of the code generate identical build IDs. What could have caused a different build ID of the different compilation, aside from last person who compiled it explicitly using --build-id=something?

If it helps, build architecture is powerpc64le.

Answer (score 1):

> I found no good explanation of what is elf-file build id

Copying from my comment on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75438715/50617): the build-id is a unique checksum added by the linker and computed over all "important" bits of the ELF file. Its primary use is to make sure that the `core` file matches the binary which produced it (build-id is located very near the start of the binary, and is included in the `core` for this purpose).

Build-id is also used to locate correct debug info -- the best practice is to build with `-O2 -g`, save this "full debug" binary, then run `strip -g exe exe.stripped` and use the `exe.stripped` in production. When you get a `core` dump from production, use the original `exe` to debug it.

> What could have caused a different build ID of the different compilation

Your build is likely not bit-identical. Actually achieving bit-identical rebuilds requires some effort.

One common cause of non-bit-identical rebuilds is using `__DATE__` and/or `__TIME__` in some message.

If you build your shared library from the same sources twice, and get a non-bit-identical rebuild, you can compare contents of each `ELF` section (using `readelf -x $section ...`). Chances are you'll find differences in `.rodata` or `.data`.